# "Most middleware" issue with running node app.js from terminal

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, terminal

I'm new to node.js, and I can't seem to run my node app.js file after adding in a new file called projects.js with only this JS code:

```html
exports.viewProject = function(req, res){
  res.render("project");
};
```

This is a pre-coded project from my (useless) professor, and I'm getting this error:

[image: terminal error for node.js]

I have Big Sur, uninstalled and reinstalled node, tried sudo, and it still doesn't work. Here is my app.js code as well, and I only added var project and app.get('/project'... etc).

[image: app.js code]

Sorry if this is lengthy, I'm just trying to make it through online classes during a pandemic. Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed your your modules. In terminal `npm install` in the root directory?

Comment: Saving the router and starting fresh is out of the question? you can use express-generator

Comment: Is the root directory where the project file folder is in? or is in my usr or macintosh HD?

Comment: @Leslie the folder the project resides in. Navigate there in terminal and execute the `npm install` command.

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I just tried to install it, and it has a permission issue. I would assume this can be fixed using sudo, but don't know how to do that for root admin.

Comment: instead of installing node directly, install nvm and you will not have the admin issue: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm tbh this made my life better hahaha

Comment: @Bibberty it's still giving me "npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/leslienguyen/IntroHCI/package.json'" error

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I installed it, and it works for other things! But it's still giving me the same error as my screenshot above when I run my lab4.

Comment: Can you share the repo of your lab to check if has some dependency issues?

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa here is the link! https://github.com/leslienguyn/lab4. Thanks for taking a look, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Leslie you created this project from scratch? or it was provided by your teacher?, what dependencies you installed by yourself?

Comment: It looks you are using very very old example code that is for older versions of express, almost all utility middleware you are adding is not included now in express and you need to install it independently (favicon, logger, session, methodOverride, cookieParser, session), app.router is deprecated also

Comment: also, why is node a dependency?

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I'm so sorry I don't know what dependency means or refers to. I don't know anything, my professor just provided us these files and we had to make changes to them (copy and paste code snippets) according to his slides. But if they're outdated, then would you recommend installing them separately? Or would it be better to modify something else?

Comment: @Leslie, don't worry it's fine, give me 5

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I commented out all the middleware in app.js, and am able to run app node.js perfectly fine now! Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it greatly. :)

Comment: @Leslie I created a pull request to your repo, check it out, I updated the express version and fixed some regression issues, should work fine now with the latest stable version of express (ported the code that you had on app.js to the new stuff).

Comment: If the pull request looks convincing enough, merget with the current master branch and re clone and reinstall dependencies with `npm i`

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa sounds good! I'll take a look at it soon and will most likely plan to merge it. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I been there, and is really hard to fix these issues without some help when you are starting on this,

Answer (score 0):

The warning that Express is giving you tells you that you're trying to use built-in middleware that [aren't included in Express anymore](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/express.js#L87-L105). Some of them have been deprecated *over 9 years* ago when Express 2.x was deprecated. The current version as of writing is 4, and version 5 is in alpha.

Some of these have not been bundled with Express since 2012 (2.x), some of them since 2015 (3.x):

- `express.favicon()` - handled by `express.static()` as long as your `favicon.ico` is inside the `public` directory
- `express.logger()` - use the `morgan` package instead
- `express.methodOverride()` - use the `method-override` package instead, although you probably don't need this
- `express.cookieParser()` - use the `cookie-parser` package instead
- `express.session()` - probably became `express.cookieSession()` in 3.x, removed after 3.x, use the `express-session` package or alternatively `cookie-session`

As Sebastián mentioned in the comments, `app.use(app.router)` is also redundant.

Additionally, the `express3-handlebars` package is also deprecated as it's for Express 3 (like the name suggests). If you go to its [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express3-handlebars), you'll see a big banner telling you to use [`express-handlebars`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) instead.

Your `package.json` file also includes a package named `node` which, according to its description, can be used to run scripts from dependencies with a specific node version. You also most likely don't need this at all, and can uninstall with npm.

As a closing statement, if the base for this project was provided to you by your educational facility, I would suggest giving them feedback and telling them that it would be time to update the examples.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed response! I do recognize that the Express middleware isn't included after doing some research. I've already tried installing express-handlebars and I get this error: "npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/leslie/IntroHCI/package.json'". I def agree with the educational feedback.

Comment: That error means that you are not inside a directory with `package.json`. Perhaps you need to `cd` to the correct subdirectory.

Comment: I tried to install it into the parent folder, and it still gave the same issue. I was able to fix this by commenting out all the outdated middleware in app.js! Thank you so much for your help :)